# Связь объектов с помощью Line Renderer

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как с помощью Line Renderer связать два объекта в Unity3D, если такое возможно? Просто обычная визуальная связь, при которой, например, объекты могут отдаляться от друг друга и сама линия также изменялась. Не судите строго, я только новичок в Unity.

Comment: у LineRenderer есть точки по которым оно рисует, так вот тебе надо в update менять 2 точки linerenderer на позиции этих двух объектов.

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: Можно найти объект с помощью Transform;
И менять позицию объекта с помощью координат другого обьекта.